# Convert MySQL login script to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

I've written a functional login script using MySQL. However, I've now been told that it needs to be done using PDO, and I've a functional PDO connection:

```
function getConnection()
{
    $userName = '*****';
    $password = '*****';
    $dbname = '******';
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $userName, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $db;
```

However I've no idea how to convert the login query to PDO.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['attempt']))
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $qry = mysql_query
        ("SELECT *
          FROM subscriber
          WHERE email = '$user'
          AND password = '$password'")
        or die(mysql_error());

    $total = mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if ($total > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = 'yes';
        header('location: account.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you read any beginner PDO tutorial? Did it say how to query the database?

Comment: @Jon: Whilst I entirely agree with your sentiment, I think the mere fact this user is actually trying to do the right thing by moving away from `mysql_query()` warrants a little more support - that's something we should definitely encourage and the more explanations there are around, the better for everyone.

Comment: @eggyal: Someone more cynical might say that this user was tasked to do something and wants to delegate the work to SO. Whatever the case may be, "I have no idea" is not acceptable here AFAIK *unless* it is accompanied by "here's what I tried" -- even if "trying" means as little as "unsuccessfully googling for a tutorial". Finally, I disagree with "the more explanations are around" idea because SO has a dupe functionality -- if wouldn't have one if we wanted a lot of scattered explanations to the same questions, don't you agree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get you started:

```
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE email = :email AND password = :password
");
$stmt->bindParam(":email"   , $user    );
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, got it working $count = $stmt->rowCount();

 
 if ($count > 0)
 {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = 'yes';
  header('location: account.php');
  exit;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Non-bloated version:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
$stm-> execute($_POST['user'], $_POST['password']);
if ($id = $stm->fetchColumn()) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
    header('location: account.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: forsure you the boss here your answers are always gentle

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this example if you would not like to use bindParam. But I extracted it from @eggyal's answer. Great thanks go to eggyal.

```
<?php session_start();
    include_once('pdo.inc.php');

    $username = (isset($_POST['username']))? trim($_POST['username']): '';
    $password = (isset($_POST['password']))? $_POST['password'] : '';
    $pas = md5($password);
    $redirect = (isset($_REQUEST['redirect']))? $_REQUEST['redirect'] :
        'view.php';
    $query = ("SELECT username FROM site_user WHERE username=:username
              AND password =:password");
    $query_login = $con->prepare($query);
    $query_login->execute(array(
        ':username'=>$username,
        ':password'=>$pas));
    $result = $query_login->rowCount();

    if($result>0)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        // Set these explicitly just to make sure
        echo 'User name invalid';
    }
?>
```